# How to run a count through an intermediary model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to find how many responses a given account has.

Here are my associations...

```
Account has_many :questions
Question belongs_to :account
Question has_many :responses
Responses belongs_to :question
```

I'm sure there are a number of ways to handle this, so whatever is the least taxing as far as DB calls go...

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there's a better way to achieve what you want using raw sql but using ActiveRecord, you should be able to achieve what you want using the following code

```
account = Account.first
Response.joins(question: :account).where(accounts: { id: account.id }).count
```

This returns the number of responses for the first account.